# How to creating an image gallery page which dynamically created by loading images from an associated directory by using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the html and js, just got a task to make a photo gallery, and the gallery page should be dynamically created by loading images from an associated directory and contain captions loaded from a configuration file located within that directory. Any one could tell me how to do it?

Comment: A very good tutorial with examples: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: This site is designed for concrete, problem-oriented questions, not tutorial requests. Google it instead.